# Merge sort doesn't work without specific variables

Tags: python, python-3.x, sorting

I have implemented a working merge sort:

```
def merge_sort(alist):
    length = len(alist)

    if length < 2:
        return

    mid = length // 2

    left = alist[:mid]
    right = alist[mid:]

    merge_sort(left)
    merge_sort(right)

    return merge(left, right, alist)

def merge(left, right, alist):
    i = 0
    j = 0
    k = 0

    while i < len(left) and j < len(right):
        if left[i] <= right[j]:
            alist[k] = left[i]
            i += 1
        else:
            alist[k] = right[j]
            j += 1
        k += 1

    while i < len(left):
        alist[k] = left[i]
        k += 1
        i += 1

    while j < len(right):
        alist[k] = right[j]
        k += 1
        j += 1

    return alist

print(merge_sort([5,3,4,2,1,6]))
```

However, if the `left` and `right` variables are removed, and all instances of them replaced with their values directly, then it stops working (the `merge` method is not changed):

```
def merge_sort(alist):
    length = len(alist)

    if length < 2:
        return

    mid = length // 2

    merge_sort(alist[:mid])
    merge_sort(alist[mid:])

    return merge(alist[:mid], alist[mid:], alist)
```

Could someone please explain what causes this?

Comment: @StefanPochmann Updated.

Comment: You sort a copy of your list, not the actual list.

Comment: @PaulRooney That is the problem, I don't understand what there is to debug, I am simply removing two variables and replacing any instance of those variables, directly with their values.

Comment: @BUZZY but I thought when you pass a list into a method it's simply the reference to the original list that's past, not a new list?

Comment: But you didn't pass that list to a method. `alist[:mid]` is called slicing and creates a new copy every single time you call it. So you basically created a copy of half of your list, sorted it, then threw it away (because it hasn't been saved in any variable). Then you did it one more time with the second half. Your original list is still the same.

Answer (score 2):

`alist[:mid]` and `alist[mid:]` each make a *copy* of the list. When you do it again in the call to `merge`, you make *another* copy that isn't sorted.

Comment: I thought when you pass a list into a method it's simply the reference to the original list that was passed, not a copy?

Comment: yes, but `alist[:mid]` creates a copy no matter what

Comment: @user9352220 the slice makes a copy, then you pass a reference to that copy into the function. The function updates that copy, but since the copy was only a temporary it gets lost after the function call. The original `alist` is never affected, even when you assigned the slices to variables.